# What does the ! mean in 'return default!;' in C# logging implementation?

Tags: c#

In the create a [custom logger example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider#create-the-custom-logger) the function `IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state);` of the `ILogger` interface is implemented as `return default!;` with no explanation of what `BeginScope` even is and why `default!` is used.

I am specifically interested why the null forgiving operator `!` was used here.

```
public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state) => default!;
```

Answer (score 5):

The `!` operator is the `null-forgiving-operator` introduced in C# 8.0. It marks things as never being null and instructs the compiler to skip null checks so you don't get a "can be null" warning. It's useful when you know a variable will never be null at a spot in your code, especially after you've used the `null-able operator` `?` to designate a variable as null-able.